# A question about regression analysis: invariance of partial R2?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, r-squared

Say we're given a design matrix $X$ as well as some invertible matrix $H$. I'm interested in the partial $R^2$ of $X_{i}$ given $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{i-1}$. $H$ is such that $e_{i}^{T}H = e_{i}^{T}$, where $e_{i}$ is the indicator vector containing all zeroes except a $1$ at the $i^{th}$ position. So this means that the $i^{th}$ row of H is itself $e_{i}.$

If we let $W = XH$, what conditions on $X$ do we need so that the partial $R^{2}$ of $W_{i}$ given $W_{1}, W_{2}, ..., W_{i-1}$ is equal to the partial $R^{2}$ of $X_{i}$ given $X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{i-1}$?
Or is it the case that the partial $R^{2}$ are invariant under transformations of the predictor variables? I'm wondering how to show this explicitly.

Comment: It looks like you've implicitly defined $H$ as the identity matrix, so $W = X H$ is equal to $X$. Is this intentional?

Comment: $e_{i}^{T}H = e_{i}^{T} $for a particular value of $i$, not for all $i$, so $H$ shouldn't be equal to the identity matrix in general.